# Need help setting up a method in a feature spec (RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

My program code works as expected, but I need help setting up a method in a feature spec using RSpec (3.1.0) & FactoryGirl.  The relevant part of my edit spec is as follows:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Editing appointments" do

  let!(:appointment) { FactoryGirl.create(:appointment) }

def update_appointment(options={})
  options[:date] ||= "2018-01-02"
  options[:starts_at] ||= "08:00:00"
  options[:ends_at] ||= "10:00:00"
  options[:member_id] ||= 1
  options[:trainer_id] ||= 1

  appointment = options[:appointment]

  visit "/appointments"
  within "#appointment_#{appointment.id}" do
  click_link "Edit"
  #save_and_open_page    
end

  select('2018', :from => 'appointment_date_1i')
  select('December', :from => 'appointment_date_2i')
  select('15', :from => 'appointment_date_3i')
  select('10', :from => 'appointment_starts_at_4i')
  select('00', :from => 'appointment_starts_at_5i')
  select('12', :from => 'appointment_ends_at_4i')
  select('00', :from => 'appointment_ends_at_5i') 

  click_button "Update Appointment"

end

it "updates an appointment successfully with corrected information" do

  update_appointment appointment: appointment,  

    date: '2020-06-11',
    starts_at: '08:00:00',
    ends_at: '10:00:00'                      

  appointment.reload

  expect(page).to have_content ("Appointment was successfully updated.")
  expect(appointment.date).to eq("2020-06-11")    
  expect(appointment.starts_at).to eq("08:00:00")
  expect(appointment.ends_at).to eq("10:00:00")

  end
end
```

When I run the spec, RSpec generates the following error message:

```
1) Editing appointments updates an appointment successfully with corrected information
 Failure/Error: expect(appointment.date).to eq("2020-06-11")

   expected: "2020-06-11"
        got: Sat, 15 Dec 2018

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -"2020-06-11"
   +Sat, 15 Dec 2018
```

Looks like the appointment is not being updated with new values. I assume this is caused by how I try to call the "update_appointment" method and/or assign new values. I don't know how best to fix the problem. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I think you don't use options. **Just select 2018 Dec 15** in `update appointment` method.
you should use options in `select` method. like below
(options[:year].to_i, :from => 'appointment_date_1i')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do not understand your advice. Please modify the code to show me how you believe I should change  my update_appointment method. How do I "just select 2018 Dec 15" in my method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to success this spec.
Please check out **I commented here** in spec file.
You selected **Dec 15 Dec 2018**. That's why the result was also **15 Dec 2018**.

Prerequisite:

```
rails g scaffold Appointment title date:date starts_at:time ends_at:time
```

Spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "Appointments", :type => :feature do
  describe "Editing appointments" do

    let!(:appointment) { FactoryGirl.create(:appointment) }

    def update_appointment(options={})
      options[:date]       ||= Date.parse("2018-01-02")
      options[:starts_at]  ||= Time.parse("08:00:00")
      options[:ends_at]    ||= Time.parse("10:00:00")
      options[:member_id]  ||= 1
      options[:trainer_id] ||= 1

      appointment = options[:appointment]

      visit "/appointments"

      within "#appointment_#{appointment.id}" do
        click_link "Edit"
        #save_and_open_page
      end

      select(options[:date].year,  :from => 'appointment_date_1i')
      # I commented here!
      select(options[:date].strftime("%B"), :from => 'appointment_date_2i')
      select(options[:date].strftime("%d"),   :from => 'appointment_date_3i')
      select(options[:starts_at].strftime("%H"), :from => 'appointment_starts_at_4i')
      select(options[:starts_at].strftime("%M"),  :from => 'appointment_starts_at_5i')
      select(options[:ends_at].strftime("%H"), :from => 'appointment_ends_at_4i')
      select(options[:ends_at].strftime("%M"),  :from => 'appointment_ends_at_5i')

      click_button "Update Appointment"
    end

    it "updates an appointment successfully with corrected information" do

      update_appointment appointment: appointment,
                         date:      Date.parse("2020-06-11"),
                         starts_at: Time.parse("08:00:00"),
                         ends_at:   Time.parse("10:00:00")

      appointment.reload

      expect(page).to have_content ("Appointment was successfully updated.")
      expect(appointment.date.to_s(:db)).to                 eq("2020-06-11")
      expect(appointment.starts_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S")).to eq("08:00:00")
      expect(appointment.ends_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S")).to   eq("10:00:00")

    end
  end
end
```

And, run `rspec spec/features/appointments_spec.rb`

```
.

Finished in 0.23874 seconds (files took 3.56 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me fix my feature spec.  Your improvements to my set-up works great.  I appreciate your help!  I added other tests, and everything passes as expected now.  I'll try to refactor this spec later to improve it.  I'm learning Rails & testing ... this has been helpful.

Comment: I'm so glad to hear it. Have great rails days :)